# How can I convert Kilometers to Meters?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have some strings that define "Kilometers", such as :

```
sValore = "64.8";
sValore = "64,8";
sValore = "64";
sValore = "64.82323523";
```

and I need a function that convert it to Meters.

First problem is to convert it on "double". I tried with :

```
double valore = double.Parse(sValore.Replace(",", "."));
```

but in fact, the result of first (64.8) is, for example, 648 (must be 64.8).

Than, doing `valore * 1000` I should resolve the problem, but what about the last case? The result must be 64823, not 64823.3523

So, how can I resolve these troubles?

Comment: Why do you have numeric values in strings to start with?

Comment: It comes from a DB, stored from a XML, is not from my system :)

Comment: use type cast to convert it to int

Comment: maybe splitting the string on ',' and '.' so you have two string, one for the integer part and one for the fractional part. Then you can join on a known seperator which should parse correctly

Comment: use the `Parse` overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` parameter, and pass the appropriate `CultureInfo` depending on whether the string uses `,` or `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: @markzzz: Part of the downvoting could be the result of your question title... Converting kilometers to meters is about as close to trivial an operation as you can get. Your question isn't really about unit conversion, but about string manipulation. Perhaps a title change is in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your problems seems to be that you have bad data where a decimal separator is represented using either a dot or a comma. If you can't fix that problem at the source you can do a replacement as you already are doing:

```
var sValore = "64.82323523";
var kilometers = Decimal.Parse(
  sValore.Replace(",", "."),
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

Notice that I specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the `IFormatProvider`. This will ensure that a dot is used as the decimal separator. Otherwise the code will break if the current culture is using a different decimal separator. (I think that is the problem you are facing - "valore" is an Italian word and that culture uses comma, not dot.)

I also parse the value into a `Decimal` because it is generally a better type for decimal numbers if you don't want to perform extensive computations on. If you want to you can use a `Double` instead.

Going from kilometers to meters is simply a matter of multiplying på 1,000. It seems that you want to represent the meters as an integer so you need to round the value and cast it:

```
var meters = (Int32) Math.Round(1000*kilometers, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you should be parsing the data into either a `double` or a `decimal`, then multiplying by 1000. Ideally, you should then *not* convert back to a string representation unless you really need to. (You may even want a data structure which is explicitly about lengths, with units, to avoid later ambiguity.)

Always try to get data into its most natural representation as early as possible, then stick with that representation for as long as possible.

Comment: The first point still a problem : double valore = double.Parse(sValore.Replace(",", ".")); return 684, not 68.4...

Comment: @markzzz: Don't call `Replace` - use an appropriate `IFormatProvider` (e.g. a relevant `CultureInfo`) which is suitable for your input. If `64.8` and `64,8` are meant to be the same thing, do you know for certain that you will never have thousands separators in your input, e.g. "68,123" which could mean "68 thousand and a bit" or "just over 68".

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @markzzz: Not really, as I don't know enough about your data. Fundamentally it looks like you've got bad data, and I don't know how you'd want to treat "68,123" which is ambiguous if you don't have any cultural frame of reference.

Comment: Ok, resolved with `int valore = (int)(Double.Parse(sValore, culture) * 1000);` : what do you think about?

Comment: @markzzz: Well yes, if you know the culture to use, that's fine - but *do* you know the different culture in each case?

Comment: Data come from "italian" datasheet, so I presume they are inserted as "italian standard". Else, I can't do nothing I think :)

Comment: @markzzz: Well if you've got both "68.4" and "68,4" and they're meant to mean the same thing, you clearly don't have one single consistent culture.

Comment: @markzzz: Oh, that wasn't shown in your "Ok, resolved with [...]" comment. You've still got the problem of what "68,123" would mean though.

Comment: 68,123 and 68.123 is the same...user can insert as he wants...that's the problem :)

Comment: @markzzz: They mean *very* different things in different cultures.

Comment: I know, you know, User Pippo doesnt know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Round()` method to round the fraction to nearest integer value, or youcan just cast the value to the integer and thus simply "drop" the fraction:

```
double rounded = Math.Round(valore);
double truncated = (int)valore;
```